# How can I generate dashboard in JMeter which will publish by extracted values; regular expression extractor

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to generate a html report in JMeter. For which I am using below command:

jmeter -n -t C:\Controlled_Environment\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin\Automation\Cursor_Leak_Report.jmx -l C:\Controlled_Environment\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin\Automation\Curosr_Leak\cursor.csv -e -o C:\Controlled_Environment\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin\Automation\Curosr_Leak\cursor

But this html reports does not shows what values I have extracted.

For example, the .jmx helps to know how many Database connection are made to the App. I am extracting the count via SQL query and using regular expression extractor. How can I show in HTML dashboard the same.

Answer (score 0):

By default it won't.

You need to:

1. Declare the variable you use in the Regular Expression Extractor as [Sample Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables), i.e. add the next line to [user.properties file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization) (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   sample_variables=foo
   ```
2. [Configure HTML Reporting Dashboard to plot the custom chart over time](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#customs_graphs) providing this sample variable, it can be done in the same user.properties file:

   ```
   jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.classname=org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.CustomGraphConsumer
   jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.title=Variable from DB over Time
   jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_Y_Axis=Variable from DB Value
   jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.set_X_Axis=Over Time
   jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_granularity=60000
   jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_Sample_Variable_Name=foo
   jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_Content_Message=Variable from DB :
   ```